# Circuit with constant output amplitude

Tags: operational-amplifier

I want to create a circuit that has an input of the form v(t) = A + Bsin(wt) where f is between 20Hz and 20kHz and B is between 1 and 6 V. How would I create a circuit that outputs the same amplitude regardless of the input amplitude using only op amps, diodes, capacitors, inductors and resistors?

Thanks.

Comment: can you use a light bulb?

Comment: Nobody asks that sort of question in the real world... just in education ... by the way ... "A" is not defined. So I assume that's also between 0 and 6V? (Based on the context and my experience of test questions...)

Comment: Your haven't given a good (any) reason for restricting the circuit to analog components, so it appears silly and arbitrary. Even low end DSPs can handle audio frequencies well enough for this task. That will be a simpler and higher quality solution than some kludgy old analog circuit. What is the point here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I create a circuit that outputs the same amplitude
>   regardless of the input amplitude using only op amps, diodes,
>   capacitors, inductors and resistors?

You need a circuit that can adjust its gain so that it can maintain the amplitude of what it produces. Without introducing serious distortion this cannot be simply achieved with the components you specify unless you were to build a linear diode multiplier circuit and this is a little complex for what I believe is your knowledge level. Sorry for the put-down but just to show what is required I'll provide some detail.

A forward conducting diode can be regarded as a voltage controlled variable resistor. If the diode is forward biased at some point on its curve, injecting a small ac signal to the bias point will produce an ac signal that is somewhat attenuated (and slightly distorted). If you adjust the bias point up and down the curve, the small ac signal can be seen to get smaller and bigger (with some variable amounts of distortion). [Here](http://ecematerial.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/small-signal-model-of-diode.html) is a site that can help you understand the issues about forward biasing a diode and here is the main diagram from that site: -

[image]

Basically, a small signal (applied via a resistor and capacitor) to the anode of a forward biased diode can be amplitude modulated by altering the bias point. To largely overcome signal distortion, you can use an inverted version of the input signal and feed this to another diode (same forward bias point) and output the differential output voltage between the two anodes: -

[image]

How does this help?

Ignoring "A" (the dc content in the OP's formula), if you feed an input signal to the circuit above (into Vin), at Vout you'll get a variably attenuated "copy" of that input. The variable attenuation is controlled by Vbias. As Vbias gets bigger Vout gets smaller.

The trick is to increase Vbias as the output ac amplitude increases. This can be done with another op-amp gain stage fed from Vout (above). This extra stage should convert the peak ac amplitude into a DC level i.e. it is a precision rectifier.

As Vout rises due to Vin rising, the precision rectifier tries to generate a bigger dc control voltage that in turn applies more bias to the diodes, which in turn reduces the Vout signal and therefore controls amplitude. The gain of the precision rectifier determines how flat the output amplitude is when changes to the input amplitude are made.

That's it in a nutshell but, this might be a little difficult if you are just starting off in electronics.

NB - the circuit above can be converted to a four quadrant analogue multiplier and works pretty well with BJTs instead of diodes too. Under simulation, using fast BJTs I reckon it's good for near-DC to 1GHz but you'd replace the op-amps with transformers. It's similar to a diode ring modulator/mixer but operates on a wholly more linear principle.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common enough problem that such a circuit has a name, called *automatic gain control*, or "AGC".

Keep in mind that when you say "constant" amplitude, it has to be over some time.  If the signal were instantaneously constant, then it would be a DC source.  Usually AGC for audio has a time constant of a few 100 ms to over a second, depending on the purpose.

The obvious and simple way to do this is in a digital processor.  Enough samples can be kept in memory so that the volume can be smoothly adjusted so that the maximum peak in memory is just at full output.  Then performing the gain function is also easy since it is just a digital multiply.

Multiplying in analog by a value on the fly is difficult.  Fortunately for AGC you only need a two-quadrant multiplier, and it doesn't need to be very linear since it is inside the feedback loop.  (To clarify, signal in to signal out must be linear, but control value input to gain output can be non-linear).  Bill Hewlett's famous oscillator circuit used the non-linear characteristic of a light bulb to provide electronically alterable gain.  I did something similar many years ago with two LEDs taped to two light dependent resistors (LDRs).  The two LEDs were driven oppositely, and the LDRs were arranged in a voltage divider.  The voltage divider then essentially replaced a potentiometer used as a volume control.

There are other schemes for electrically controlled gain, but again, this is really asking for a digital imlementation today.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a top down approach to your circuit.

1. What systems do you need? amplification? DC blocking or Current pumps? Feedback?
2. Begin building each of these with your available components. If you need amplification look at op-amps. charge pumps will need caps or ind
3. With these basic blocks built you can start piecing them together.

Make sure to look at the overall picture (voltage nodes, current paths, etc) and make sure that these blocks don't produce undesired affects when put together. Stepping back at each step and looking at the overall goal again can show over complications in your circuit and maybe even shortcuts

I know this is a bit of a general answer but a more direct answer can probably be found in the back of the textbook where this question came from (though it may only have the odd answers).